# What is client request?

Tags: http, go

In the below code(`../src/net/http/request.go`):

```
// For server requests, the URL is parsed from the URI
    // supplied on the Request-Line as stored in RequestURI.  For
    // most requests, fields other than Path and RawQuery will be
    // empty. (See RFC 7230, Section 5.3)
    //
    // For client requests, the URL's Host specifies the server to
    // connect to, while the Request's Host field optionally
    // specifies the Host header value to send in the HTTP
    // request.
    URL *url.URL
```

---

URL `protocol://hostname:port/resource_path` is used as part of GET/POST/.. request to server but not client

---

What does client request mean, in the above comments?

Answer (score 2):

From [the Request type documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request)

> *A Request represents an HTTP request received by a server or to be sent by a client.*

And right above your comment...

> ```
> // URL specifies either the URI being requested (for server
> // requests) or the URL to access (for client requests).
> ```

A web browser make a client request. A web server receives a server request.